# Convert String Long Date time to Short Date (MM/DD/YYYY) ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Need help converting Oct 7, 2021 4:57 AM(String) to MM/DD/YYYY in ADF. I am using derived column, but must be missing something. Help is greatly appreciated.

[DataFlow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFP3q.png)

Comment: @AaronBertrand They will know that 10/07/2021 is October 7th. The business is US based.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yup never outside of the US. I dont really make the rules, I just abide.

Comment: Currently using this. toString({Date of Answer},'MMM DD, YYYY HH:MM A') Which is returning the string, just not sure how to convert that to Date and MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: @AaronBertrand I ran that, and it displayed the same value in the string.

Oct 7, 2021 4:27 AM